# Solving Integro-Differential Equation with Numerous Dependencies Using DSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

I am attempting to solve equation (3.9a) from the [paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/article/on-the-equation-for-sphericalparticle-motion-effect-of-reynolds-and-acceleration-numbers/6EB5B8498F16A624399925048A0C506E) "On the equation for spherical-particle motion: effect of Reynolds and acceleration numbers" to characterize the response of a particle to background fluid forcing. The equation takes the following form (after some simplification):

$$ \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{9 \nu_{F}}{2 a(1+\frac{\alpha}{2})} \int_{0^{+}}^{t} K[t-\tau, \tau] \frac{d(u - v)}{d\tau} \, d\tau \;+ \;...$$

Other terms in the equation are ignored (for the purpose of not making this post unnecessarily complicated). The kernel K is expressed as follows:

$$ K(t-\tau,\tau) = \quad \left( \left( \frac{\pi (t-\tau)\nu_{F}}{a^2} \right)^{\frac{1}{2c_{1}}} + G[\tau] \left( \frac{\pi |u(\tau)-v(\tau)|^3}{2 a \nu_{F} f_{H}^3(Re_{T})} \times (t-\tau)^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{c_{1}}}  \right)^{-c_{1}}$$

The equations upon which K depends are listed as follows:

$$ w = \left| u - v \right|$$

$$ Re_{T} = 2wa\nu_{F}$$

$$ f_{H} = 0.75 + c_{5} \times Re_{T}$$

$$ Ma_{1} = \left( \frac{2a}{w^2} \right) \times \left| \frac{dw}{d\tau} \right|$$

$$ Ma_{2} = \left( \frac{4 a^2}{w^3} \right) \times \left| \frac{d^2w}{d\tau^2} \right|$$

$$ \phi_{R} = \frac{Ma_{2}}{Ma_{1}}$$

$$ \beta = \frac{c_{2}}{1 + \frac{\phi_{R}^{c_{4}+1}}{c_{3} \left( \phi_{R} + \phi_{R}^{c_{4}} \right)}}$$

$$ G(\tau) = \frac{1}{1 + \beta(Ma_{1}(\tau))^{0.5}}$$

I have attempted to apply the following code to solve $\frac{dv}{dt}$, but have thus far been unsuccessful:

```
    (* Initialization - Set Constants*)
    alpha = 10;          (* fluid-to-particle density ratio *)
    a = 2*10^-3;         (* particle radius [m] *)
    rhoF = 998.21;       (* density of fluid, [kg/m^3] *)
    muF = 0.0010016;     (* dynamic viscosity of the water [Pa*s] *)
    nuF = muF / rhoF;    (* kinematic viscosity of water[m^2/s] *)
    Sset = 10;            (* dimensionless frequency *)
    OmegaNew = 2*Sset/alpha;
    Omega1New = OmegaNew/(2*(a^2)/(9*nuF*alpha));
    fNew = Omega1New/(2*Pi);
    f = fNew;            (* finds the frequency from the set dimensionless frequency *)
    Omega1 = 2*Pi*f;     (* angular frequency *)
    Omega = Omega1*2*(a^2)/(9*nuF*alpha);
    v0 = 0; (*IC*)
    xi = 0.005;
    xF = xi*a;
    
    (* Constants for G and f_H functions *)
    c1 = 2.5;   (* constant *)
    c2 = 22.0;  (* constant *)
    c3 = 0.07;  (* constant *)
    c4 = 0.25;  (* constant *)
    c5 = 0.126; (* constant *)
    
    (* Define the function f_H(Re_t) *)
    ReT[w_] := w*2*a/nuF;
    fH[ReT_] := 0.75 + c5 * ReT;
    
    (* Define the velocity function of the background fluid u *)
    u[t_] := xF*Omega1*Sin[Omega1*t];
    
    (* Define w as the absolute value of the relative velocity *)
    w[u_, v_] := Abs[u - v];
    
    (* Define the function G along with functions it depends upon *)
    MA1[tau_,v_] := (2*a/(w[u[tau], v]^2))*Abs[D[w[u[tau], v], tau]];
    MA2[tau_,v_] := (4*a^2/(w[u[tau], v]^3))*Abs[D[w[u[tau], v], {tau, 2}]];
    phiR[tau_,v_] := MA2[tau,v]/MA1[tau,v];
    beta[tau_,v_] := c2 / (1 + phiR[tau,v]*(phiR[tau,v]^c4) / (c3 * (phiR[tau,v] + phiR[tau,v]^c4)));
    G[tau_,v_] := 1 / (1 + beta[tau,v]*MA1[tau,v]^0.5);
    
    (* Define the kernel function K *)
    K[tmtau_,tau_, v_] :=\[IndentingNewLine]
    (((Pi * (tmtau)* nuF/ (a^2))^(1/(2*c1))) + G[tau,v] *(( (Pi * w[u[tau], v]^3 / (2*a * nuF * fH[ReT[w[u[tau], v]]]^3)) * (tmtau)^2)^(1/c1) ))^ (-c1);
    
    (* Define problematic history integral *)
    historyIntegral[t_, v_] :=\[IndentingNewLine]
      Limit[(9*nuF/(2*a))* Integrate[K[t - tau, tau, v[tau]]*D[u[tau] - v[tau], tau], {tau, lim, t}]/(1 + alpha/2), lim -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"];
    
    (* Solve the abbreviated integro-differential equation using DSolveValue *)
    odeFuncWithInt[t_, v_] := historyIntegral[t, v];
    solHist = DSolveValue[{v'[t] == odeFuncWithInt[t, v[t]], v[0] == v0}, v, {t, 0, 1}]
```

I have consulted the Mathematica [documentation](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/symbolic-and-numeric-calculus/solve-an-integro-differential-equation.html) for solving integro-differential equations (hence the use of `v[tau]` in the `historyIntegral` equation) but have been unsuccessful thus far in finding a suitable solution. Any and all help is appreciated (and if answering clarifying questions on my end would be helpful, please let me know), thanks very much.

Comment: Why not to solve it numerically?

Comment: @AlexTrounev using NDSolveValue you mean? I hadn’t seen anything in Mathematica’s documentation about numerically solving integro-differential equations, so I guess I wanted to try first using DSolveValue since they had explicit documentation related to integro-differentials. That strategy was probably misguided, but I’m still getting up to speed with Mathematica’s capabilities as a new user. Thanks!

Comment: There are several numerical methods to solve this kind of equations. See for example iterative method proposed by Ulrich below.

Comment: It looks like your definitions `MA1, MA2` are not same as in the paper sited.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Are you saying that because I'm differentiating with respect to $\tau$ instead of $t$? It seems to me like the paper (e.g. in the case of $Ma_{1}$ in equation 3.9c) is differentiating with respect to $\tau$, since for example $Ma_{2}$ is a function of $t$ and $t$ only appears in the second derivative term, although I of course acknowledge that both $\textbf{u}$ and $\textbf{v}$ are time-dependent vectors.

Comment: If we take `MA2` as it is then we need to put initial condition for $v'(0)$ as well, while in your code there is `v[0]=0` only.

Answer (score 4):

**modified**

Here is an iterative numerical solution

$v_{n+1}(t)=\int_0^t \left(u'(\tau )-v_n'(\tau )\right) K\left[t-\tau ,\tau ,v_n(\tau )\right] \, d\tau$

which seem to converge very fast.

First change `Abs` to `RealAbs` in the initialization

```
  (* Initialization - Set Constants*)
    alpha = 10;          (* fluid-to-particle density ratio *)
    a = 2*10^-3;         (* particle radius [m] *)
    rhoF = 998.21;       (* density of fluid, [kg/m^3] *)
    muF = 0.0010016;     (* dynamic viscosity of the water [Pa*s] *)
    nuF = muF / rhoF;    (* kinematic viscosity of water[m^2/s] *)
    Sset = 10;            (* dimensionless frequency *)
    OmegaNew = 2*Sset/alpha;
    Omega1New = OmegaNew/(2*(a^2)/(9*nuF*alpha));
    fNew = Omega1New/(2*Pi);
    f = fNew;            (* finds the frequency from the set dimensionless frequency *)
    Omega1 = 2*Pi*f;     (* angular frequency *)
    Omega = Omega1*2*(a^2)/(9*nuF*alpha);
    v0 = 0; (*IC*)
    xi = 0.005;
    xF = xi*a;
    
    (* Constants for G and f_H functions *)
    c1 = 2.5;   (* constant *)
    c2 = 22.0;  (* constant *)
    c3 = 0.07;  (* constant *)
    c4 = 0.25;  (* constant *)
    c5 = 0.126; (* constant *)
    
    (* Define the function f_H(Re_t) *)
    ReT[w_] := w*2*a/nuF;
    fH[ReT_] := 0.75 + c5 * ReT;
    
    (* Define the velocity function of the background fluid u *)
    u[t_] := xF*Omega1*Sin[Omega1*t];
    
    (* Define w as the absolute value of the relative velocity *)
    w[u_, v_] := RealAbs[u - v];
    
    (* Define the function G along with functions it depends upon *)
    MA1[tau_,v_] := (2*a/(w[u[tau], v]^2))*RealAbs[D[w[u[tau], v], tau]];
    MA2[tau_,v_] := (4*a^2/(w[u[tau], v]^3))*RealAbs[D[w[u[tau], v], {tau, 2}]];
    phiR[tau_,v_] := MA2[tau,v]/MA1[tau,v];
    beta[tau_,v_] := c2 / (1 + phiR[tau,v]*(phiR[tau,v]^c4) / (c3 * (phiR[tau,v] + phiR[tau,v]^c4)));
    G[tau_,v_] := 1 / (1 + beta[tau,v]*MA1[tau,v]^0.5);
    
    (* Define the kernel function K *)
    K[tmtau_,tau_, v_] :=\[IndentingNewLine]
    (((Pi * (tmtau)* nuF/ (a^2))^(1/(2*c1))) + G[tau,v] *(( (Pi * w[u[tau], v]^3 / (2*a * nuF * fH[ReT[w[u[tau], v]]]^3)) * (tmtau)^2)^(1/c1) ))^ (-c1);
    
    (* Define problematic history integral *)
    historyIntegral[t_, v_] :=\[IndentingNewLine]
      Limit[(9*nuF/(2*a))* Integrate[K[t - tau, tau, v[tau]]*D[u[tau] - v[tau], tau], {tau, lim, t}]/(1 + alpha/2), lim -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"];
```

Please check the kernel, perhaps I missed something.

```
    sol = NestList[
   int[t_?NumericQ] := 
    NIntegrate[(((Pi*(t - tau)*nuF/(a^2))^(1/(2*c1))) + 
        G[tau, # &[
           tau]]*(((Pi*
               w[u[tau], # &[tau]]^3/(2*a*nuF*
                  fH[ReT[w[u[tau], # &[tau]]]]^3))*(t - tau)^2)^(1/
             c1)))^(-c1), {tau, 0, t }, 
     Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]; 
   NDSolveValue[{v'[t] ==   9*nuF/(2*a (1 + alpha/2)) int[t] , 
      v[0] == v0}, v, {t, 0, 1}, MaxStepSize -> .01] &, v0 &, 10] // 
  Quiet
 Plot[Through[sol[t]], {t, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for responding, this looks great! When I try to run the code you've proposed, Mathematica returns multiple errors for NIntegrate ("tau = t is not a valid limit of integration) and NDSolveValue ("Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives"). Would you be OK with please sending me the full code you used (my email is in my Profile section) or otherwise providing further guidance? Thanks again!

Comment: In case it’s helpful context, I’m using Mathematica Version 14.0.

Comment: @BenjaminTarver I checked the code, separated the integrationpart and corrected some cut&paste errors. Now code should run! My version: Mathematica v12.2. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for the follow-up and the well wishes, I really appreciate it! For me, the code you updated now seems to be plotting a flat line with zero variation with time, whereas the behavior of the result is expected to be oscillatory. Would you be able to please advise further on this matter?

Comment: Didn't you get this parabolic shape shown in my answer?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I obtain the same thin blue line on the time axis that your graph displays from t = 0 to 1.

Comment: Start with fresh kernel , evaluate your code block and evaluate the code in my answer

Comment: My apologies, I should have elaborated on my process in my previous response. When I start a fresh kernel, then evaluate the code block I wrote (minus the DSolveValue command), and then evaluate the code in your answer, I get the result I described, along with the error "InterpolatingFunction: Input value {0.000020428571428571424`} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used"

Comment: Can't believe it. What is content of  `sol` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151389/discussion-between-benjamin-tarver-and-ulrich-neumann).